# How to increase maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When signing an apk, I got this message:

```
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 4608 MB (based on the dexOptions.javaMaxHeapSize = 4g).
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
```

In my project, I don't have a gradle.properties file, but I have a file called gradle-wrapper.properties.

I opened that file and added the line `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M`.

After that, I tried to sign the apk again but I'm still getting the message of increasing Gradle heap size.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It currently has approximately 910 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090135/to-run-dex-in-process-the-gradle-daemon-needs-a-larger-heap-it-currently-has-a)

Answer (score 79):

If you don't have `gradle.properties` then go to your project folder you will find gradle files there create a text file and name it as `gradle.properties` removing `.txt` and then add the below code to that file.

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

and save it then open your project in Android Studio and click on sync now.

I hope it will resolve your issue, if not please let me know.

Comment: of if you already have `gradle.properties` file in `android` folder add this line `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m`

Answer (score 32):

I know you said your project doesnt have `gradle.properties` but you could create a global one in `C:\Users\user\.gradle` and add:

```
 org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
```

And remember to run `gradle --stop` to kill any previous daemons.

Comment: I have tried this to no avail. I even created the command line variable GRADLE_USER_HOME=C:\Users\<MY USER>\.gradle.  I also tried putting it in my platform/andorid/gradle.properties but it continues to use 2048MB

Answer (score 12):

You can try any one of the following

**1) change the gradle.properties file and change the heap size as per your requirement.**

If **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M** is not sufficient then change to **4096** as given

**org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M**
[image]

**2)"Edit Custom VM Options" from the Help menu.**

It will open studio.vmoptions / studio64.exe.vmoptions file
[image]

Change the content to

-Xms128m

-Xmx4096m

-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m

-XX:+UseCompressedOops

Save the the file and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224255/to-run-dex-in-process-the-gradle-daemon-needs-a-larger-heap-it-currently-has-9) answer**

```
dexOptions 
   {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
   }
....
....
....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Android question, but it pops up for *scala out of memory gradle* search anyway, so let me try to save some poor souls hours of searching.

Scala forks the JVM by default when compiling, and *org.gradle.jvmargs* do not apply to it. Instead, you have to pass the args to the Scala plugin in gradle. It depends on your particular setup on where that might be, for me, this works:

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    configure(scalaCompileOptions.forkOptions) {
        jvmArgs = ['-Xss4m', '-Xmx2048m']
    }
}
```

If your build is comprised of multiple subprojects, put this inside the `subprojects { }` block inside the main *build.gradle*.

Answer (score -2):

Add following code to your build.gradle file.

```
 android {
     dexOptions {
     incremental true       
     javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
      }
    }
```

Reference : [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/r4p-sBLl7DQ)

Comment: that is not the same the message is telling to do. Maybe your way is the old way?

Comment: also i noticed that i currently have that line added,     dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Comment: so it is not the solution, because with that line i'm getting the message

Comment: What message are you getting?

Comment: @VishvaDave I have added source link. Check that. There are so many question have same code that does not mean that code is copied. Even almost all devloper use this code snippet in all application development for hit size issue.

Comment: dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}

Try this

Comment: @SamirBhatt Actually this question is duplicate. you should give possible link in comment. avoid answering this type of duplicate questions.