# GC overhead limit exceeded when uploading symbols to Crashlytics

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Our android/NDK/C++ UE4 game project used to successfully upload symbols to crashlytics during builds but yesterday we suddenly started getting this error during uploads:

Execution failed for task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsRelease'.

> GC overhead limit exceeded

Should we be using a different version of crashlytics now or something?

Our build.gradle includes the following:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

crashlytics {
  enableNdk true
  manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
  androidNdkOut 'src/main/jniLibs'
  androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/jniLibs'
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
       compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        // NDK Kit
        compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.5'
}
```

as a post build step we invoke

gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease

Comment: Can you add which version of the Fabric Gradle plugin you're using? `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'

Comment: classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+' 

Shall I try switching to 1.27.1?

Comment: Yep, try explicitly setting that.

Comment: Switching to 1.27.1 did not fix the issue unfortunately. We also tried increasing the java heap to 8GB with no luck.  Anything else we should try?

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to support(at)fabric(dot)io with the build logs and errors so they can dive in more.

Comment: Will do. Thanks

Comment: I'm hitting the GC overhead limit with 1.27.1, 1.28.0, and 1.28.1.  It works fine on 1.27.0, but that version causes gradle deprecation warnings (which disappear with 1.28.0) so hopefully they realize this is a regression and fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem last week and it appears to be a bug with Fabric's gradle plugin version 1.27.1. When I reverted the plugin to 1.27.0 uploading symbols worked fine.

Force the version in your build.gradle:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
```

Comment: Sadly, forcing to 1.27.0 resulted in the same error for us

Comment: You could try forcing 1.27.0 and algo increasing Gradle's max heap size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454257/how-to-increase-maximum-heap-size-for-the-gradle-daemon