# flutter: can't build app bundle for google play when i add admob: JVM garbage collector thrashing and after running out of JVM memory

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, android-studio

i have flutter app and already upload it and publish in google play, but when i add google_mobile_ads code, the app run perfectly in emulator but i can't build app bundle for google play. this is error appear:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon has been stopped: JVM garbage collector thrashing and after running out of JVM memory.

Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

and i try many sizes in gradle.properties org.gradle.jvmargs but same issues face.

this is doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.18.0-18.0.pre.47, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3803], locale ar-OM)
    • Flutter version 3.18.0-18.0.pre.47 on channel master at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 3df4e735d5 (4 days ago), 2023-12-29 14:07:39 -0500
    • Engine revision 9e03a57cde
    • Dart version 3.3.0 (build 3.3.0-273.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.31.0-dev.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: F:\android-studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at F:\android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 12 (API 32) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3803]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.130
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.91

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic
data along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash
reports. This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework,
and related tools.
```

any help?

any help and suggest to build app bundle for google play?

Comment: Try changing the heap size for the JVM doing the build.

Comment: See [How to increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454257)

Comment: @StephenC i tried all that but still not solved

Comment: What did you set it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by increasing the _JAVA_OPTIONS in Environment Variable to -Xmx2048M

thank you @StephenC